# Why can't I update and remove or add new User

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, save, fxml

Any body please help me, when I click on update or save user the hibernate sql exception code appears and I cannot find out how to fix it.

So please help me!!!
//Update I've removed MainBase and integrated code session management in to UserDAO.

```
public void setText(User user) {
    this.txtUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
    this.txtFullname.setText(user.getFullname());
    Date birthdate = user.getBirthdate();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(birthdate);
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    //get Day Month Year tu birthdate he thong
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //Month bat dau tu 0
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    //dinh dang ngay thang DatePicker
    String pattern = "dd-MMM-yy";
    dpBirthdate.setConverter(new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

        @Override
        public String toString(LocalDate date) {
            if (date != null) {
                return dateFormatter.format(date);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
            if (string != null && !string.isEmpty()) {
                return LocalDate.parse(string, dateFormatter);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
    this.dpBirthdate.setValue(LocalDate.of(year, month, day));
    this.txtAddress.setText(user.getAddress());
    this.txtEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
    this.txtPhonenumber.setText(user.getPhonenumber());
    this.cbxRole.setValue(user.getRole());
}
public void btUpdate(ActionEvent evt) {
    User user = dao.getByUsername(this.txtUsername.getText());
    getText(user);
    if (this.dao.save(user)) {
        clearText();
        tableUser();
    }
}
```

User DAO

```
 public User getByUsername(String username) {
        open();
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = (User) ss.get(User.class, username);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Get Username \n" + ex);
        }
        close();
        return user;
    }

public boolean save(User user) {
    try {
        ss.beginTransaction();
        ss.save(user);
        ss.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error Save User \n" + ex);
        ss.getTransaction().rollback();
        return false;
    }

}
```

When I click update or add user this show exception

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1423)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.songhuy.dao.UserDAO.save(UserDAO.java:96)
    at com.songhuy.gui.controller.UserController.btAdd(UserController.java:252)
    ... 57 more
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 42 seconds)
```

Comment: The exception says your session is closed. Include the code where you manage the session. (Typically you would do something like `Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` etc.)

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed! Means that when you try to invoke the database action the Session is already closed.

Comment: Show `com.songhuy.hibernate.MainBase.open`.

Comment: I've just change my code but cannot add and update :(

Comment: anybody help me please:(

Comment: looks like you are closing session in getByUsername, when try to save your session is already closed.

Comment: About the comment that you can't update the question. If you are using Mozilla Firefox sometimes an error happens updating the question.So if you are updating the question as StackOverFlow accepts it then one solution is to click the update button multiple times,actually it may take 15 button clicks :).Seems like a bug.